# I have enabled tags for my AWS ECS services, I was not able to see it or filter it in my cost explorer

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, amazon-ecs, aws-cost-explorer

I have enabled AWS ECS tags for all the services, but I was not able to see those tags in cost explorer, I have activated the cost allocation tags both user defined tags and AWS managed tags from the billing account. I have added these tags and activated it a month ago, but I was not able to see those tags. I'm also using the new ARN format
Some suggested me to add propagate tags while creating the service, But I don't the exact reason.
And this happens only for the ECS, for other services it's working fine and I was able to see the tags in cost explorer.

I tried updating my service by adding propagate tags, but I don't know how long it'll take to reflect, I don't even know whether enabling this propagate tags will work or not.
Please help me with this problem